# How to set a Report Viewer's report language programmatically?

Tags: reportviewer, globalization

Do any of you know if it's possible, and how, one can set a report viewer's report language programmatically?

For example, something like this:

```
var reportviewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.LocalReport.Language = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
```

Or more specifically, if it's possible to set the report language to a custom culture and how?

Comment: I don't know about specifically setting it on the report viewer itself, but the report viewer will use the culture set with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that this is particularly for ReportViewer, but if you are creating a localreport programatically (.rdlc), there is no need to change the users culture. Open the rdlc report and in the Report's properties set the 'Language' property to a Parameter of your choice e.g.

```
=Parameters!ReportLanguage.Value
```

You cannot set this property to a dataset field unfortunately (at least not in Visual Studio 2013)

In the ReportData screen (Ctrl + ALT + D), Create a parameter called 'ReportLanguage'. You only need to set the name, you don't need to add any extra details.

In a textbox on your report, set a FormatCurrency expression

```
=FormatCurrency(Fields!UnitPrice.Value, 2)
```

This will format the currency of the textbox value to whatever the Language of the report is (to 2 decimal places)

Now in the code generating the report (C#), set the ReportLanguage parameter

```
LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();

localReport.ReportPath = pathToMyRdlcFile;
localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("ReportLanguage", "en-GB"));
```

"en-GB" will give you a pound sign when the report is generated, but you can get a euro symbol by using "fr-FR" or similar.

Indeed you could replace the hardcoded "en-GB" with a function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to set the report's Language to the expression "`=User!Language`" and then to change the thread culture before rendering the report.

If you edit your report in VS you can easily achieve the first part in the designer (open rdlc in designer, go to properties, select Report from list of objects in the rdlc, edit property Language), then for the second:

```
var cultureBkp = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
// Build report ...
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureBkp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set in pageload

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP");

Answer (score 0):

To expand @tzup's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27520558/6868927); there are two settings namely

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

The former sets the built-in field `User!Language` while the latter influences among others, the language of the buttons such as `View Report`, the language of the text in the loading screen in the report viewer component.